# Sending push notifications to a list of friends in an Android Native App

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, push, native

I am creating a native Android application that sends push notifications to a specific list of friends. How to send push notifications just to this specific list in Android ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Push Notification mainly sends from server, from application side you must need to create one Browser Key on Google Api Console, after creating your app there and need to activate GCM from there.

Then, you need to give GCM Registration Id to your server and then whatever push you want to fires, server triggered one query with it and will send push to all your friends list.

Comment: So, I need a centralized server, and not one on each android phone ?

Comment: nop, you need to centralize server, and need some code at server side also.

Comment: Accept and upvote the answer please, so other people could take benefit of it.

Comment: So, I have to implement the server. Is it in Android or PHP ?

Comment: it will be on php, Java or whatever technology you can use

Answer (score 1):

Take a look the [Urbanairship](http://urbanairship.com/), it provides send the notification by registered tag/id, and also provide broadcast notification.